# accessing existing attribute returns null

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, sax

i wrote the below expression to retrieve info from the below xml file, but the returned results is null and index out of bound.

please let me know how to retrieve data from this element:

```
 <ele k="maxspeed:zone" v="60"/>
```

**expression**:

```
"//node[@lat='53.0337395'] [@lon='8.8489255']/following-sibling/following-   
sibling::ele[1]/@v"
```

**xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<osm>
<node id="25779111" lat="53.0334062" lon="8.8461545"/>
<node id="25779112" lat="53.0338904" lon="8.846314"/>
<node id="25779119" lat="53.0337395" lon="8.8489255"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>
<ele k="maxspeed:zone" v="60"/>
<node id="25779114" lat="53.334062" lon="8.841545"/>
<node id="25779117" lat="53.338904" lon="8.84614"/>
<node id="25779110" lat="53.33795" lon="8.489255"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="32"/>
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="no"/>
</osm>
```

Comment: try `//node[@lat='53.0337395'] [@lon='8.8489255']/following-sibling::ele[1]/@v`. in your xpath the second segement `following-sibling` was treated as element name, thus returning null result

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there - you need to add `::tag[1]` to the first `following-sibling`, like this:

```
"//node[@lat='53.0337395'] [@lon='8.8489255']/following-sibling::tag[1]/following-sibling::ele[1]/@v"
```

This retrieves `Attribute='v="60"'`